# rhino mocks with singleton

Tags: .net, singleton, rhino-mocks

I'm using component from a third party. The component provide a singleton pattern for context into our application. I'm using on my side this singleton but I would like to mock this object for my test. Is there any way to accomplish a mock on this object.

Also, the constructor is declared private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With RhinoMocks you have to have an interface. If you really need to mock this, then you will have to cheat a bit by wrapping the singleton in another class that instantiates an interface. This interface needs to basically be a carbon copy of all public members on the third party singleton type.

The concept is similar to [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), but since the CLR doesn't support Duck Typing you have to use the proxy class.

Here is an example:

```
public interface ISingleton
{
    void SomePublicMethod();
    Int32 SomePublicProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class SingletonProxy: ISingleton
{
    private ThirdPartySingleton _singleton = StaticType.GetSingleton(); // ???

    public void SomePublicMethod()
    {
        _singleton.SomePublicMethod();
    }

    public Int32 SomePublicProperty
    {
        get{ return _singleton.SomePublicProperty; }
        set{ _singleton.SomePublicProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

So now in whatever type you are using this in, you can pass this in as a service dependency like so:

```
public class TypeThatUsesSingleton
{
    private ISingleton _singleton;    

    public TypeThatUsesSingleton([HopefullySomeDependencyInjectionAttributeHere] ISingleton singleton)
    {
        _singleton = singleton;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _singleton.SomePublicMethod();
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to happily mock the class in your test and pass it in as the dependency in order to get your unit tests rolling along:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldAssertSomeBehavior()
{
    var repo = new MockRepository();
    var singleton = repo.DynamicMock<ISingleton>();

    var sut = new TypeThatUsesSingleton(singleton);

    using(repo.Record())
    {
        singleton.SomePublicMethod();
    }
    using(repo.Playback())
    {
        sut.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Voila! Happily mocked singleton without the headache (ok, so a little headache). You are probably thinking that the whole Proxy class is going to be a pain in the butt, but luckily some good folks have made this a little easier. The whole Duck Typing thing I mentioned earlier... there is an open source library that will generate your proxy class for you at runtime.

[Duck Typing .Net](http://www.deftflux.net/blog/page/Duck-Typing-Project.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the third party Singleton returns an interface rather than a concrete class (it should), then Rhino mocks will be able to mock it.

If you just want to stub it out, check out Rhino mocks' `MockRepository.Stub<IMyInterface>()`